# .sh file as installer

Tags: linux, yum

how to create installer of .sh file on linux ,so that i can install it 
using yum command

plz anybody help me?

Comment: Your question is: "How can I package a single script into a RedHat RPM?"

Comment: Found an example here: http://lincgeek.org/blog/?p=303

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with the Fedora ecosystem but as far as I know, `yum` is a layer on top of plain old `rpm` to resolve dependencies and fetch packages which it installs. The `rpm` format contains metadata that the package maintenance system can use to keep track of what is installed, what was pulled in etc.

A shell script doesn't have any of this so it doesn't really fit into the whole scenario properly. If you want your application to be installable via. `yum`, you'll need to package it as an rpm and make the repository available.